# How to pass metadata to QnAMaker Request

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I am trying pass metadata filter to my QnAMakerDialog request but cannot figure out how to do it.  I have tried adding the values to the dialog that is forwarded but this did not work.

**LuisDialog.cs** method that calls QnAMaker

```
public List<Metadata> _metadataFilter { get; set; }

[LuisIntent("")]
[LuisIntent("None")]
public async Task NoneIntent(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> message, LuisResult result)
{
    string filterValue = context.UserData.GetValue<string>("filter");
    var messageToForward = await message;
    var qnaDialog = new QnADialog();
    _metadataFilter = new List<Metadata>()
    {
        new Metadata()
        {
            Name = "filter",
            Value = filterValue
        }
    };

    await context.Forward(qnaDialog, AfterQnADialog, messageToForward, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

**QnAMakerDialog.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using QnAMakerDialog;
using QnAMakerDialog.Models;

namespace ChatBot.Dialogs
{

    [Serializable]
    [QnAMakerService("","","")]
    public class QnADialog : QnAMakerDialog <bool>
    {

        public override async Task NoMatchHandler(IDialogContext context, string originalQueryText)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Sorry, I don't know '{originalQueryText}' yet");
            context.Done(this);
        }

        public override async Task DefaultMatchHandler(IDialogContext context, string originalQueryText, QnAMakerResult result)
        {
            // Posting top QnA Maker result to user
            var messageActivity = (result.Answers.First().Answer);
            await context.PostAsync(messageActivity);
            context.Done(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The QnAMakerServiceAttribute includes the metadata filter, however it is a list and my understanding is you cannot add a list to attribute.

**QnAMakerServiceAttribute.cs**

```
using QnAMakerDialog.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace QnAMakerDialog
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Interface, AllowMultiple = true)]
    [Serializable]
    public class QnAMakerServiceAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string BaseUri { get; set; }

        public string EndpointKey { get; set; }

        public string KnowledgeBaseId { get; set; }

        public int MaxAnswers { get; set; }

        public List<Metadata> MetadataBoost { get; set; }

        public List<Metadata> MetadataFilter { get; set; } 

        public QnAMakerServiceAttribute(string baseUri, string endpointKey, string knowledgeBaseId, int maxAnswers = 5)
        {
            this.BaseUri = baseUri;
            this.MaxAnswers = maxAnswers;
            this.EndpointKey = endpointKey;
            this.KnowledgeBaseId = knowledgeBaseId;
        }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> trying pass metadata filter to my QnAMakerDialog request but cannot figure out how to do it.

You can refer to the following code snippet to specify `MetadataFilter` for your QnADialog.

```
var qnaDialog = new QnADialog()
{
    MetadataFilter = new List<Metadata>()
    {
        new Metadata()
        {
            Name = "filter",
            Value = filterValue
        }
    }
};

await context.Forward(qnaDialog, AfterQnADialog, messageToForward, CancellationToken.None);
```

The above code work for me, and if use fiddler to capture request, we can find the request body contains "*strictFilters*":

[image]

Comment: This what I get from fiddler POST data ```{
  "question": "what is fte",
  "top": 5,
  "strictFilters": [],
  "metadataBoost": [],
  "userId": "QnAMakerDialog"
}```

Comment: my strict filters are empty

Comment: Your code of _metadataFilter would not apply to your QnADialog. You can modify your code as I did in the reply?

Comment: That worked thank you, I had a typo when I modified to match yours